# Test target of XCUITest seems not to be working after updating to Xcode 10

Tags: xcode10, xcuitest

I updated to xcode 10 from Xcode 9.4 and then when trying to run my UI tests nothing seems to be working. The test app loads for a while then test failed although the build is successfully done before the tests.
and the source code builds successfully as well and I can run the app on the simulator.

The error is:

`Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: The test runner failed to load the test bundle. Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements mismatch.))`

Comment: Xcode 10.1 or 10 ?

Comment: I have the same issue on Xcode 10 / Xcode 10.1... Do you have a workspace with multiple project/frameworks?

Comment: Xcode 10.1 yesI have a workspace with many frameworks yes but only one project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you are using Cocoapods make sure your test target has the inherited search paths set up, something like that for instance :

```
# MARK: Common pods
abstract_target 'AppCommon' do
  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'MyFrameworkA' do
    project './MyPath/MyFrameworkA/MyFrameworkA.xcodeproj'

    target 'MyFrameworkATests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
    end
  end
end
```

Next, in your **Build phases** of your ***FrameworkA***, make sure that any other frameworks (B, C used in A), are set up as **target dependencies** AND added to the **Linked Binary With Libraries**.

Finally, make sure your ***FrameworkATests*** target have your *FrameworkA* in **Target Dependencies** and is added in the **Linked Binary With Libraries** phase too.

Comment: But I need to understand why this was happening. what is the difference now in Xcode10?

Comment: Great news! Forget my question about Xcode 10, I had the same issue and my debugging was in progress. It's the same with Xcode 9 if I remember well. But the compiling issue may also be related to the new Build System updates. You can see it in the File / Workspace Settings / New Build System (Default).

Comment: Also make sure you don't import any pods twice, f.e. by declaring it again at a subtarget

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 10 introduced new build system which parallelise the most of the building talks including the dependencies. The new build system can detect most of the configuration issues. Must of the projects which has unusual configuration started to fail and new build system has detected this. All things that you should know about build system  https://www.xcteq.co.uk/xcblog/five-things-you-must-know-about-xcode-10-new-build-system/